# Generic return types for a method in an interface

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface for a node: each node has an `ID`. However, different types of nodes have IDs that can be either integers or Strings. How can I make my interface accommodate the same thing that just has different types?

```
public interface Hyperspacable {


public int getDimensioninality();

/*
 * Returns the Hyperspacable's object at this dimension
 */
public double getDimValue(int depth);

public double getLat();
public double getLon();
public String getID();


/*
 * Calculates the distance between two Hyperspacable objects of the same dimension
 */
public double distance(Hyperspacable e) throws DifferentDimensionException;
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Kindly show us your code.

Comment: Can't you convert the int IDs to String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need two distinct ID types, I can think of a couple of possibilities: you can make your interface generic or you can replace the `getID()` method with two methods `getIntegerID()` and `getStringID()` (one of which will return `null` when the other type applies). For the generic interface approach:

```
public <T> interface Hyperspacable {
    public T getID();
    . . .
}
```

For both approaches, the integer-valued ID types will have to return an `Integer` rather than an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

What if you parse the String to an Integer or the Integer to a String? So all results are the same type? You could parse it later back if you need to use the value again.

```
String.valueOf(int)
Integer.valueOf(String)
```